# Is it possible to add the feature of "Share link to this question" in the Stack Exchange application for mobiles?

Tags: feature-request, ios-app, sharing

The Stack Exchange app is one of the best apps I have on my Iphone and I just love it.
Sometimes, I wish to send a link to a question by email or sms but the app lacks the feature to share links.
Is it possible to add it?